# Chain rule for function on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

If we have a function $u: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ with $w \in \partial B(0,1)$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ then it follows that

> $$\frac{d}{dt}u(x+tw) = Du(x+tw)\cdot w$$

where $Du := \nabla u$(the gradient of $u$).

How does this follow exactly? I know it follows from the chain rule but not sure how exactly? Thanks.

Comment: $\frac{du(x+tw)}{dt}=\frac{du(\phi)}{d\phi}\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ where $\phi=u+tw$. So where do you confuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ are continuously differentiable functions and let $h:=f\circ g$ be the composition of both functions. Then the chain rule states that, for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$\frac{dh}{dt}(t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(g(t))\cdot \frac{dg}{dt}(t),$$

where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z)$ denotes the vector of partial derivatives of $f$ evaluated at $z$ and $\frac{dg}{dt}(t)$ the vector of derivatives of the components of $g$ evaluated at $t$. In your case you have that $f(z)=u(z)$ and $g(t)=x+tw$, so

$$\frac{dg}{dt}(t) = w$$

and

$$\frac{dh}{dt}(t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x+tw)\cdot w.$$